# Add pattern to LaTeX table cell

Tags: tables, pattern

I created I timetable using the LaTeX tabular environment, and I want to add diagonal strips to some empty cells, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

This is the pattern I would like to have:

[image]

How can I do it? Here is the code I used to generate the table:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,multirow}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=3.8cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \large
  \centering
  \caption{{\Large 08/01/2024 $\rightarrow$ 13/01/2024}}
  \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{cyan!30}}l|c|c|c|c|c|}
      \cline{2-6}
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \cellcolor{cyan!30}8:30-10:30 & \cellcolor{cyan!30}10:30-12:30 & \cellcolor{cyan!30}12:30-14:30 & \cellcolor{cyan!30}14:30-16:30                                                       & \cellcolor{cyan!30}16:30-18:30                                                \\ \hline
      Lundi                 &                               &                                &                                &                                                                                      &                                                                               \\ \hline
      Mardi                 &                               &                                &                                &                                                                                      &                                                                               \\ \hline
      Mercredi              &                               &                                &                                &                                                                                      & \cellcolor{red!30}\parbox[c]{3cm}{Droit\\{\small Ms Y}} \\ \hline
      Jeudi                 &                               &                                &                                &                                                                                      &                                                                               \\ \hline
      Vendredi              &                               &                                &                                &                                                                                      &                                                                               \\ \hline
      Samedi                &                               &                                &                                & \cellcolor{red!30}\parbox[c]{3cm}{Informatique\\{\small Mr X}} &                                                                               \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a pdf of the pattern and include it as an image. Looking at the pattern if it gets slightly distorted it will look ok. Also please modify the code to be a full MWE (minimum working example), starting from `\documentclass`  to `\end{document}`. Table looks good otherwise, I tried it out. Remove things not needed for the problem at hand like Tifinagh writing etc.

Comment: I updated the question, thank you.

Comment: With the `nicematrix` package, you can use Ti*k*Z to add the pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the patterns.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=3.8cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand{\MyBlock}{\Block[transparent,tikz={pattern = north west lines, pattern color = red}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\large
\centering
\caption{{\Large 08/01/2024 $\rightarrow$ 13/01/2024}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\columncolor{cyan!30}}X[l]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines,color-inside,width=0.8\textwidth]
  \rowcolor{cyan!30}
           & 8:30-10:30 & 10:30-12:30 & 12:30-14:30 & 14:30-16:30  & 16:30-18:30 \\ 
  Lundi    &            &             & \MyBlock{*-1}{}  \\
  Mardi    &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Mercredi &            &             &             & \MyBlock{}{} & \Block[fill=red!30]{}{Droit\\ \small Ms Y} \\ 
  Jeudi    &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Vendredi &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Samedi   &            &             &             & \Block[fill=red!30]{}{Informatique\\ \small Mr X} & \MyBlock{}{}\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

---

Here is a version with an empty corner in position NW (*north west*). The key `corners` of `nicematrix` has been designed for that job but, for technical reasons, it does not work with cells of type `X`. That's why I have used a column type `l` for the first column.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm,bottom=3.8cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand{\MyBlock}{\Block[transparent,tikz={pattern = north west lines, pattern color = red}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\large
\centering
\caption{{\Large 08/01/2024 $\rightarrow$ 13/01/2024}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\columncolor{cyan!30}}lX[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]}[hvlines,corners=NW,color-inside,width=0.8\textwidth]
  \rowcolor{cyan!30}
           & 8:30-10:30 & 10:30-12:30 & 12:30-14:30 & 14:30-16:30  & 16:30-18:30 \\ 
  Lundi    &            &             & \MyBlock{*-1}{}  \\
  Mardi    &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Mercredi &            &             &             & \MyBlock{}{} & \Block[fill=red!30]{}{Droit\\ \small Ms Y} \\ 
  Jeudi    &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Vendredi &            &             &             &              &             \\ 
  Samedi   &            &             &             & \Block[fill=red!30]{}{Informatique\\ \small Mr X} & \MyBlock{}{}\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works properly, but it does not recreate the borderless, colorless, top-left cell of the table.